# C# Antlr: is there a way to have aliasses be generated as array when used inside *?

Tags: .net, antlr4

I'm using nuget package Antlr4.Runtime.Standard v4.11.1 in .NET 6 and have this grammar rule:

`term           : factor ( op = ( PLUS | MINUS ) factor )* ;`

Note that alias `op` is inside the `*`. *PLUS* and *MINUS* are defined as '+' and '-'

But, when i put this in the parser and my custom visitor:

`1+2-3`

... the generated context in my visitor gives me `factor` as an array of 3, but `op` as a single field, containing only the last occurrence '-'.

So, is there a way to get all occurrences of that `op`, somehow? Or do I have to process rules like this by walking the children array, and finding out what is what myself?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` in ANTLR just (re) assigns the token to `op`. To collect all tokens, you can do `+=`:

```
term
 : factor ( op+=( PLUS | MINUS ) factor )* 
 ;
```

where `op` will now be a list of tokens. Or just don't use `*` at all:

```
term
 : factor ( ( PLUS | MINUS ) term )?
 ;
```

in which case you'll always have only 1 expression to evaluate (if `PLUS` or `MINUS` is present).

Comment: Oh, that second example makes it all so much more elegant... my visitor code doesn't have to loop anymore. thanks!